# How to add rails html tags though Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to add rails html code using jquery, but didn't work.
Code that i have tried:

```
   <% @user.each do |record| %>    
      <tr>
       <td>
         <%=  record.name %> 
       </td>
       <td>
         <%= record.gender %>
       </td>
      <%= record.dob %>
       </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
 <button id="edit_button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm edit" onclick="editRow();">更新</button>
  

  function editrow(){
     var $item = $('.edit').closest("tr").find(".nr");
         var name = "<%= text_field 'name', class: 'form-control' %>"
         $item[0].innerHTML= name;
   }
```

but it didn't work giving error like name is undefined method.
also tried with different, but old value didn't displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You can't dynamically insert ERB tags.
The order of rendering an ERB goes something like this:

```
Rails reads ERB and renders HTML+assets -> 
HTML+assets get returned to your browser -> 
Your browser renders HTML and executes JavaScript
```

Your browser can't read ERB :(

Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to do with the "editrow" function, as well as show us more of the ERB?

Comment: onclick `editRow` function make input field in row with displaying old value in input.

Comment: @vvp45 how about render both raw value and `<input />`? when edit button get clicked, just toggle the css class name to hide/show the element.